# Revert from Reserve instance to RDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I purchase AWS EC2 Reserved instance for 1 year.Am trying to install sqlserver express 2008r2 on the windows data center edition on this vm. Base on the error message am getting, it seems express edition of sqlserver cannot be install on this platform.I noticed, for my need purchasing RDB for 3 years would even cost less than what i have paid for the EC2.Now i want to determine that instance and go for the AWS RDB for the same payment made. Did anyone have ideoa whether this is possible, because once the instance is determine no cost should be applied but my worried is by purchasing a reserve instance for 1 year is a commitment made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great that you got the solution to your core problem yourself!

For those who wants an answer to your initial question :
AWS dont allow swapping of resources for same price.

However, there is an option by which you can sell your unused reserved instance capacity in the reserved instance market place and get back the money to your bank.You can find more details on this here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ri-market-general.html#ri-market-selling-guide

Hope this clarifies the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I finally installed the express edition sqlserver by turning oof security setting on IE.